# Как узнать состояние select'а?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

У меня на сайте клик по объекту вызывает функцию, которая добавляет на странице новый `DIV` с формой. В этой форме есть `select` и `button`. Как сделать, чтобы нажатие на `button` показывало состояние `select`'а? Заранее спасибо.

**UPD:** Кажется нашел причину, но исправить все равно не получается. Проблема в том, что jQuery обращается к элементам DOM-дерева, которых еще нет. Вариант

```
$(".add button").live("click", function(){
b=$('option:selected').attr('value');
alert(b);
}
```

тоже не работает.

Comment: а если обернуть в $(function(){}) ???

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#div .button").live("click", function(){
    alert($('#div .select').val());
}
```

Внимание: в скрипте button и select - классы.

Answer (score 0):

наверное как то так

```
  $("button[name=имя_кнопки]").click(function(){
           $("select[name=имя_селекта]").val();
           return false;
  });
```

Comment: Что-то не работает :(

Comment: 1)ну естественно нужно подключить jQuery<br/>
2)$("select[name=имя_селекта]").val(); - это ваше значение - делайте с ним что угодно